# Extract only the second match to a Regular Expression in Ruby using standard library

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm writing a Ruby script to go through a text file and pull the second occurrence of a Regular Expression pattern in each line. Here is an example one line of text:

```
gi|324021737|ref|NM_001204301.1|    gi|324021738|ref|NP_001191230.1|    100.00  459 0   0   1080    2456    294 752 0.0  905
```

The number I'm trying to get is the one that is `gi|324021738` in the above example, but not the `gi|324021737` that comes at the beginning of the line. These values always begin with `gi|`, but the number of digits following them varies.

What would be the most efficient way to append only the second match to the Regex to an array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex: -

```
"^gi.*?(gi\|\d+).*?$"
```

And get the group 1 out of it.

Answer (score 2):

This would be better processed using `split('|')` than a regex:

```
array = []

text = 'gi|324021737|ref|NM_001204301.1|    gi|324021738|ref|NP_001191230.1|    100.00  459 0   0   1080    2456    294 752 0.0  905'
array << text.split('|')[4, 2].map(&:lstrip)
=> [["gi", "324021738"]]
```

Pipes ("|") are often used to delimit fields in a database output, similar to a comma-separated value file (CSV).

Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) is even a better choice:

```
require 'csv'

text = 'gi|324021737|ref|NM_001204301.1|    gi|324021738|ref|NP_001191230.1|    100.00  459 0   0   1080    2456    294 752 0.0  905'

array = []
CSV.parse(text, :col_sep => '|') do |row|
  array << row[4, 2].map(&:lstrip)
end

array
=> [["gi", "324021738"]]
```

The reason using CSV might be better than splitting, and especially better than a simple regex, is a delimited file often will escape the delimiting character when it's embedded inside another field. A regex to capture that condition is very difficult to write and maintain. `split` could do the wrong thing too, which is why it's better to rely on a pre-built/pre-tested "wheel", like CSV.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few seconds to understand the regex posted by @Rohit.

Here is an alternative answer using split.  Split the string into groups using the " " character (space).  Then split the element at index 1 using the "|".  Get the element at index 1.  That is the number you are looking for.

```
s = "gi|324021737|ref|NM_001204301.1|    gi|324021738|ref|NP_001191230.1|    100.00  459 0   0   1080    2456    294 752 0.0  905"
s.split(" ")[1].split("|")[1]

=> "324021738"
```

Comment: What if space doesn't exist? It's a pad character filling out fields to a set width in the database field. This is a very fragile solution.

Comment: Fragility is in inherent in parsing a record like this.  Regular expressions are fragile as well.  The issue I have with regular expressions is that they can be harder to read.  Splitting strings is easier to understand.  "Split at the space...Split at the |...etc."

Comment: I agree that `split` is better, however, splitting on a character that is a true delimiter is even better. `|` is the field delimiter in this sample, not `' '`, which is a filler and could be missing.

Comment: @theTinMan Records should have clear delimiters.  This record has a clear delimiter; space.  It separates fields of different types.  The first two fields are of the same type, and have a delimiter within them; '|'.  The other 8 fields are numeric; "100.00", "459", etc.